# Width of Zone on Search page

Tags: web-part, css, web-part-zone

The SP Search page has only 1 zone.  I used DOM Explorer to find its id is MainZone.  I added some script to the page via Snippet Web Part:

```
#MainZone{width:800px;overflow:auto;}
```

It does nothing.  Any suggestion how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

This is something that I use in day to day implementations, may not be the best approach out there but is a dirty fix :)

---

If the top level container doesn't allow applying of css. It means one of the children containers have their own CSS that overrides the top level css.

Press f12 > developer options > select the element container that you want to apply css. Add the relevent styling (like width: 100px) in the element.style. If the style doesnt apply, then continue iterating into the children containers, until it does apply.

Below is an example :-

[[image: 1]]

Answer (score 0):

Changing the WP area probably works just as you are doing it, but it doesn't affect the content inside the WP which has its own defined `width` preferences. In addition to adjusting the `width` of the WP area, you'll want to do the same for the search item, and for the search item's body text. As mentioned, these have a pre-defined styling, so the changes also need to be forced with a `!Important` as follows:

```
.ms-srch-item, .ms-srch-item-body {
    width: 800px !Important;
}
```